# rails view has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I have such two models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :articles_type
end




class ArticlesType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

and in controller i write:

```
@articles = Article.where(article_type_id: params[:id])
```

and in view(haml) i try:

```
= @articles.articles_type.id

= @articles.articles_types.id

= @articles.first.articles_type.id

= @articles.first.articles_types.id
```

how could i display this articles_type.id but for only first row?

now i get

```
undefined method `articles_type'
```

but why? what i do wrong? how to display nested model id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The undefined method message is because `@articles` does not have an `articles_type` method. You have to get to a single instance of an Article in order to use that method. You could do that with a call to `@articles.first` or by iterating on the collection.

```
= @articles.first.articles_type.id
```

is the line you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

`@articles` will be a collection of items, not just a single one (because you used the `where` method). You will have to do:

```
@articles.first.articles_type_id
```

(Also note that you don't have to do `.articles_type.id`, because the `@articles.first` already has the ID of the type)

Comment: no, what if i want to fetch from ArticlesType some field called a_text ?

Comment: Yes in that case you will want to do `@articles.first.articles_type.a_text`. It all depends on what you want to do. If you ever do want to just access an ID though, and your model already has the ID, then it's better to just access it from that model for performance and optimization reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got your logic backwards.

Based on your models, an article belongs to an article_type.

```
@articles.first.article_type.id
# OR @articles.first.article_type_id
```

Just looks like you're incorrectly pluralizing `.article_types` when it should be `.article_type`.